# Disable all php errors with htaccess file

Tags: php, apache

How can I disable all php errors using my htaccess?
I don't have access to the php.ini file on my server.

Can I hide errors using some code in htaccess?

Comment: You could correct them, so they won't appear anymore...

Comment: This is not quite the same as the linked question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following line to your .htaccess file in the Root directory

```
  php_value display_errors Off
```

This tells the apache web server to hide   php errors for all directories and sub directories on the server.

Comment: Thanks it worked, But now other pages where I turned on error reporting are not opening. what could be the problem?

Comment: @Tim3111 you have turned off the php errors, remove the error reporting too.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding these lines to your `.htaccess` file and upload it to root directory.

```
php_flag display_startup_errors off
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag html_errors off
```